# regex if capture group matches string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I need to build a simple script to hyphenate Romanian words. I've seen several and they don't implement the rules correctly.

```
var words = "arta codru";
```

Rule: if 2 consonants are between 2 vowels, then they become split between syllables unless they belong in this array in which case both consonants move to the second syllable:

```
var exceptions_to_regex2 = ["bl","cl","dl","fl","gl","hl","pl","tl","vl","br","cr","dr","fr","gr","hr","pr","tr","vr"];
```

Expected result: ar-ta co-dru

The code so far:
https://playcode.io/156923?tabs=console&script.js&output

```
var words = "arta codru";
var exceptions_to_regex2 = ["bl","cl","dl","fl","gl","hl","pl","tl","vl","br","cr","dr","fr","gr","hr","pr","tr","vr"];

var regex2 = /([aeiou])([bcdfghjklmnprstvwxy]{1})(?=[bcdfghjklmnprstvwxy]{1})([aeiou])/gi;

console.log(words.replace(regex2, '$1$2-'));
console.log("desired result: ar-ta co-dru");
```

Now I would need to do something like this:

```
if (exceptions_to_regex2.includes($2+$3)){
  words.replace(regex2, '$1-');
}
else {
  words.replace(regex2, '$1$2-');
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work because I can't just use the capture groups as I would a regular variable. Please help.

Comment: Try `.replace(/[aeiou](?:(?=[bcdfghptv][lr])|[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy](?=[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy][aeiou]))/g, '$&-')`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEAS9m/2/).

Comment: Thank you. If you'll add as an answer I'll accept. I frankly didn't even think to look at it this way. I wanted to find a way to use captured groups as js variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may code your exceptions as a pattern to check for after a vowel, and stop matching there, or you may still consume any other consonant before another vowel, and replace with the backreference to the whole match with a hyphen right after:

```
.replace(/[aeiou](?:(?=[bcdfghptv][lr])|[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy](?=[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy][aeiou]))/g, '$&-')
```

Add `i` modifier after `g` if you need case insensitive matching.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEAS9m/2/).

**Details**

- `[aeiou]` - a vowel
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?=[bcdfghptv][lr])` - a positive lookahead that requires the exception letter clusters to appear immediately to the right of the current position
  - `|` - or
  - `[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy]` - a consonant
  - `(?=[bcdfghj-nprstvwxy][aeiou])` - followed with any consonant and a vowel
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

The `$&` in the replacement pattern is the placeholder for the whole match value (at regex101, `$0` can only be used at this moment, since the Web site does not support language specific only replacement patterns).