# add exception to a regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm doing a Romanian hyphenation script. 
Previous question (solved) is here: [regex if capture group matches string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360766/regex-if-capture-group-matches-string) in case you want to take a look
This is a regex that deal with vowels that are not diphthongs or triphthongs:

```
(?:[aeiou])(?=[aeiou][bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]{0,})
```

I cannot seem to figure how to add two exceptions to this: "ii" in final position remain together. The "ii" group is usually preceded by a consonant, except in the case of "copiii" which is hyphenated -pi-ii
https://regex101.com/r/ew4JUh/1
The expected result, except for the word "copiii" is always a consonant (or more) followed by the "ii" group in the same syllable
muschii = mus-chii
pomii = po-mii

EDIT:

Just in case someone ever needs to do the same, you can find the script so far here:

https://playcode.io/156923

It works - mostly.

It implements the rules as I understand them. The only issue is that probably half the words stand in exception to the rules. So while the script does what it should, it cannot deal with exceptions that cannot be anticipated.

Ex:

avion = a-v**i-o**n

iodat = **io**-dat

piatra = p**ia**-tra

diamant = d**i-a**-mant

And so on ad infinitum. 
I don't believe there's any rule to establish when the vowels are grouped as diphthongs or triphthongs and when they belong to different syllables.

On the plus side I know more grammar and more regex than ever :)

Many thanks to Wiktor who helped immensely.

Comment: I think you are looking for `(?!ii\b)[aeiou](?=[aeiou])`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXZOqS/1).

Comment: Hello and thank you again. Add it as the answer. I liked the second better: https://regex101.com/r/ew4JUh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?!ii\b)[aeiou](?=[aeiou])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VXZOqS/1).

Note that `[bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]{0,}` at the end of the positive lookahead is redundant, it makes no difference if you require an optional pattern or not.

**Details**

- `(?!ii\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is `ii` followed with a word boundary
- `[aeiou]` - a vowel
- `(?=[aeiou])` - that must be followed with another vowel.

Comment: No, [bcdfghjklmnprstvwxyz]{0,} is not the right way to do it. What I wanted to say was that this rule applies only if these 2 vowels are not followed by another vowel.  It should have been [^aeiou], right?

Comment: @flish That restriction [would not let](https://regex101.com/r/qredF9/1) matching `i` in `piii`. Are you sure you want that restriction?

Comment: It's complicated. What I want actually is to combine this here: (?!ii\b)(?:[aeiou])(?=[aeiou]) with the rest of the vowels rule : https://regex101.com/r/KPnEgy/1/ (?:[aeo])(?=[iu][aeo])|(?:[aeiou])(?=([i][a][ui]|[e][ao]|[i][aeo]|[o][a]|[u][a]))

Comment: @flish Sorry, this is not clear how you want to combine these regexps. BTW, the regex you posted above can be written as `[aeo](?=[iu][aeo])|[aeiou](?=(?:ia[ui]|e[ao]|i[aeo]|[ou]a))`

Comment: (?!ii\b)(?:[aeiou])(?=[aeiou])  this one splits 2 vowels in different syllables (except for ii in final position.                                                                                         
The other one [aeo](?=[iu][aeo])|[aeiou](?=(?:ia[ui]|e[ao]|i[aeo]|[ou]a)) deals with diphthongs and triphthongs where vowels are followed by other vowels. Ideally they would be merged into a single regex which covers both cases. The problem is that this (?!ii\b)[aeiou](?=[aeiou]) would split to different syllables the vowels which need to remain together.  I don't know how to put them together

Comment: @flish Let me share some hints. 1) Identify the more generic pattern, i.e. the one that matches all or more cases than the second one, then 2) if both match different cases, you may OR the patterns, `p1|p2` 3) if they may match the same strings, try to restrict the more generic pattern with the second one.